# What does the ring $R[x,\frac{1}{x}]$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying algebraic geometry. I looked up the solution of a problem where there is a ring $R[x,\frac{1}{x}]$ ? What are the elements of this ring ?

Is this description correct ?

$$R\left[x,\frac{1}{x}\right]=\left\{\sum_{n=k}^{l}a_nx^n\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}a_n\in R, k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

(Basically "polynomials" where instead of stopping at the constant term, negative powers are also allowed.)

Comment: Yes, exactly (with $l\in\mathbb{Z}$ also).

Comment: Also worth noting that this ring is called the ring of Laurent polynomials (in one variable) over $R$.

Comment: We know that $R[x]$ is a PID when $R$ is a field. Can we say something similar about $R[x,\frac{1}{x}]$ ?

Comment: It's a ring of fractions of a P.I.D., hence a P.I.D. itself.